# Computer crashes first 1-3 times on startup

Tags: windows-8, boot, crash, hardware-failure, desktop-computer

Whenever I start my computer, the first 1-3 times it crashes when I try to click the start menu in Windows 8.1 or before I even get there. The third or fourth time i reset my computer it works just fine and seems to have no problems at all. When my computer crashes, Some sort of 16-bit purple and blue colored screen appears. The cursor of my mouse becomes a large white square and I am unable to do anything with the computer.

Anyone knows what's going on?

My System:

```
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 920 @ 2.67GHz
Manufacturer    Intel
Speed   2.7 GHz
Number of Cores 8
CPU ID  BFEBFBFF000106A5
Family  06
Model   1A
Stepping    5
Revision
Video Card  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 280
Manufacturer    NVIDIA
Chipset GeForce GTX 280
Dedicated Memory    1.0 GB
Total Memory    4.0 GB
Pixel Shader Version    4.0
Vertex Shader Version   4.0
Hardware T & L  Yes
Vendor ID   10DE
Device ID   05E1
Plug and Play ID    VEN_10DE&DEV_05E1&SUBSYS_055710DE&REV_A1
Driver Version  9.18.13.4052
Memory  8.2 GB
Operating System    Microsoft Windows 8 Professional Edition (build 9200), 64-bit
Service Pack    0
Size    64 Bit
Edition Professional
Version 6.2.9200
Locale  0809
BIOS    BIOS Date: 09/21/10 09:55:06 Ver: 08.00.15
Version American Megatrends Inc. 1408
Manufacturer    American Megatrends Inc.
Date    09/21/10
Display Maximum Resolution  1920 x 1080
Sound Device 1  High Definition Audio Device
Driver Version  6.2.9200.16653
Sound Device 2  NVIDIA Virtual Audio Device (Wave Extensible) (WDM)
Driver Version  
DVD DTSOFT Virtual CdRom Device
CD  DTSOFT Virtual CdRom Device
Drive 1 
Size    385.7 GB
Free    37.5 GB
Drive 2 
Size    80.0 GB
Free    17.3 GB
Software    
Java    7.0.710
Flash   15.0.0.239
DirectX 11.0
.NET    3.5.30729.4926
QuickTime   7.76.80.95
Adobe PDF Reader    10.1.2.45
```

Comment: Just in case the problem is idiosyncratic to your hardware, could you edit your question to add your system information (computer brand/model, graphics card model, computer age).  How long has the problem been happening?  Any system changes (hardware or software) recently?  How soon after bootup does it happen?

Comment: Added my system info. The problem started occuring since a few months ago. Nothing specifically triggered the crashes as far as I can remember.

Comment: Have you updated your drivers?

Comment: I have updated my drivers and can now confirm that the crash only happens when I press the start button in the bottom left of the screen. But still, after 2-3 restarts, it works fine and no problems occur whatsoever...

Answer (score 0):

Try "Automatic Repair" of the Operating System and Ensure all your required security patches are installed.

Automatic Repair: To enable automatic repair while you boot, please try the steps below:

Press Windows key + C > Settings > Change PC Settings > Update or Recovery > Recovery > Advanced Startup > Restart now. Now you will prompt to "Choose an option" > Troubleshoot > Advanced Options > Automatic Repair.

Also, ensure all windows updates are installed from "Windows Update" and "Check for Updates"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have tried to execute a startup repair, but after a couple of minutes i get the notification that the computer can´t be repaired using startup repair. It then refers to a logfile srttrail.txt. The txt file has the following contents: Test performed :

Name: Internal status check
Result: Completed. Error code = 0x0
Time = 0 ms

Test performed :

Name: Test startup state
Result: Completed. Error code = 0x0
Time = 16 ms

Found root cause :

The boot state indicates that the operating system is started.